# Custom navigation bar in wordpress. How to properly style it?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and making my very first theme from scratch. I can sort of cheat my way into making a navigation with bootstrap, but I still don't understand how to make small customization I'm looking for.

Would someone please walk me through this line of code and how the things I put in the array = things I put in my CSS sheet?

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array()); ?>
```

No matter what I seem to put in the array or what tutorials I seem to follow I'm unable to match up my navigation bar with what I want to edit in my CSS sheet.

Right now I'm following a tutorial that had me change it to:

```
    <div class="navigation">
    <a class="responsive"><span></span></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'top',
        'container' => '',
        'container_class' => false,
        'menu_class' => 'nav',
        'menu_id' => 'top-menu',  
    )); ?>
    <div class="clear"></div></div>
```

Unfortunately, none of the .nav components or things I implement seem to be responding. I'm still stuck with the basic list. I know my CSS sheet should be hooked up correctly because I can still alter my background colors and other components. I just can't seem to touch the navigation bar and style it how I wish.

Comment: It would be good to see your rendered html and the corresponding CSS.

Comment: header.php: https://pad.riseup.net/p/d69NfGY3TTUkl-H6UPy3-keep

CSS: https://pad.riseup.net/p/haJlRBxrPHmZPep3kkBL-keep

The last tutorial I attempted to follow: http://mandmwebsolutions.com/blog/how-to-style-wordpress-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to design [navigation bar](https://www.ibenic.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-menu-walker-nav-menu-class/) and customize to work with Bootstrap, you will need to set menu walker, here's a source to [Wordpress menu walker with Bootstrap and how to use it](https://wp-bootstrap.github.io/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/) :)